# When Material UI Slider components are wrapped and returned, they do not work smoothly when written in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to return the Material UI's Slider and Slider's value as shown below, but why doesn't the Slider work smoothly the way I call it in JSX?

SliderAndValue.js

```
import { Slider } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export const SliderAndValue = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(30);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  const MySlider = () => (
    <div>
      <Slider
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        aria-labelledby="continuous-slider"
      />
    </div>
  );

  return { MySlider, value };
};
```

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { SliderAndValue } from "./SliderAndValue";

export default function App() {
  const { MySlider, value } = SliderAndValue();
  const { MySlider: funcMySlider, value: funcMyValue } = SliderAndValue();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {value}
      {/* It doesn't work smoothly. */}
      <MySlider />
      {funcMyValue}
      {/* Works smoothly. */}
      {funcMySlider()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-einstein-eh5so

Comment: `useSlider` should be renamed something else as it's not a hook; it's just a component.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `<MySlider>` will be re-rendered every time the state changes, but using `{funcMySlider()}` is a bit like use React.memo - it doesn't render the whole component again each time, and you get a smooth experience.